# Upgrading from basicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding: connection fails

Tags: .net, wcf, security, authentication

I maintain a program that sends messages between users. The clients connect to a WCF-service that is hosted in IIS 7.0 on my domainserver. Up to now I successfully used basicHttpBinding for this, without any configuration. Now, I want to change to wsHttpBinding because this should encrypt the transport of the messages. The server has a certificate installed, but I did nothing to make this work with the WCF service. I did not configure any options for the wsHttpBinding either.

Now, when I connect to the WCF-service from any client that is within the domain that is governed by the same server that hosts the WCF-service all is well. But when I try to connect to the service from a client outside the domain the connection fails. The client gets an exception stating that "the caller was not authenticated by the service". So it must be an authentication problem.

How do I troubleshoot this? A pointer to some helpful resources about this subject is very welcome too.

EDIT:
So here is how I got it working. Hopefully it will save some of you a headache...

The problem was as follows:

- IIS hosted two websites: mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com
- I wanted to host the WCF service on www.mydomain.com as I had purchased a certificate for that URL.
- WCF threw the error 'This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.' at me.
- you have to solve this by adding a baseAddressPrefixFilter
- I wanted just transport security, no User Authentication
- After I solved that one I got an error stating that: 'The provided URI scheme ‘https’ is invalid; expected ‘http'
- This error is generated by the *client*, not by the server.

Here is the web.config that did the trick:

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
          <add prefix="http://www.mydomain.com"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
     </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyApp.MyService">
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
           />
    <endpoint address="wsHttp"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="NoAuthentication"
                  contract="MyApp.IContract"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoAuthentication">
         <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Last, but very important: I had to tell the client that it should use the transportsecurity mode too, as I did not create the client with svcutil.

```
 public static IContract GetContract()
        {
            var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport) {MaxReceivedMessageSize = 655350};
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(
                          binding,
                          new EndpointAddress(@"https://www.mydomain.com/MyService.svc/wsHttp"));
            return factory.CreateChannel();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected default behavior. WsHttpBinding by default will use Windows credentials for authenticating your callers. This works in your domain - but fails outside it.

What you need to do is either have a second endpoint that also uses the wsHttpBinding, but different security settings, or you need to switch the entire authentication mechanism to something that works inside and outside your domain - either username/password against e.g. ASP.NET membership system on your server-side, or you'll need to install a certificate on the caller's machines.

**Update:** the ultimate reference would be the [WCF Security Guidance on Codeplex](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com) which has plenty of How-To's and Step-by-Step instructions on how to do specific security-related operations in WCF.

Comment: Thank you, my understanding of this problem had progressed to about what you explained. Where to find noob-palatable resources about deploying a certifcate with a ClickOnce application or else how to implement ASP.Net membership on the server?